# What's the tag (formal-systems) for?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-wikis

What's the tag [formal-systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formal-systems) for?

Just meta theory? Meta theory and formal proofs? Other options?

**Edit:** In view of the comments to this question and due to the fact there have been a lot of questions asking for formal proofs, should the tag (formal-proofs) be created? Most of these questions are either about natural deduction or Hilbert type system, There is a tag called (natural-deduction), but there's nothing for the rest. I think getting rid of (natural-deduction) and creating (formal-proofs) is appropriate. The other option is to include the tag (Hilbert-system) or similar.

Comment: Diplomacy, politics and other formal channels between conglomerates of humans.

Comment: A quick perusal of the questions seems to suggest we don't need the tag. It's been applied to questions on [tag:propositional-calculus], [tag:first-order-logic], [tag:formal-languages], [tag:lambda-calculus], [tag:computability], [tag:computational-complexity], which are all more descriptive than `formal-systems`. Apart from a hypothetical question on [Hofstadter's MU puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MU_puzzle), I'm having trouble thinking of a `formal-systems` question that would not fit into one of the above listed tags.

Comment: @ArthurFischer So what happens now? Should it be banned? By the same token isn't the tag [(analysis)](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/analysis/info) in the same boat as (formal-systems)?

Comment: @GitGud: Thankfully the [tag:formal-systems] tag is small enough that we could remove it from all questions within a fairly short period of time, a short time after which it would be deleted from the system. The [tag:analysis] tag is somewhat too big for that, so if there is consensus that it carries too little information, it _might_ be a candidate for burnination/blacklisting. (I _almost_ feel the same way about the [tag:logic] tag.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer I will help out in removing the (formal-systems) tag. I think the (logic) tag is appropriate because MSE doesn't deal only with mathematical logic and the (logic) tag might encompass some of the non-mathematical logic questions. Regarding (analysis), should I open a new question or will you?

Comment: @ArthurFischer I am not sure how this discussion diverged to ([tag:analysis]) tag, but there are people who would prefer keeping the tag. It was discussed [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/analysis-tag); I don't remember discussion about this tag on meta.

Comment: @MartinSleziak It's clear how (analysis) came up in the conversation, its in the same position as (formal-systems). From what I can see in the chat, the reasons for not removing the tag are logistics. That doesn't seem good enough to me, specially since [SE can deal with them easily](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/14981/homework-tag-should-be-deprecated#comment56484_14981).

Comment: Although t.b. is not active at MSE at the moment, I do respect his opinion. So [his opposition](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740?m=5656663#5656663) against removing ([tag:analysis]) is sufficient to me to say that this should not be done without previous discussion and reaching some kind of community consensus. (And in general, I think that removing big tags, like [homework](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/14981/homework-tag-should-be-deprecated) or analysis, should not be done without discussion on meta.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I agree. In fact I suggested creating a new question for that effect in a comment above.